# I'm trying to unlock my Google Stadia controller, do I need bluetooth on my PC?

Tags: google-chrome, bluetooth, game-controller

I'm trying to unlock my Google Stadia controller with [this procedure](https://stadia.google.com/controller/index_en_GB.html) on my Windows 10 desktop PC (it doesn't have Bluetooth wireless).

I got as far as doing the four finger salute (<kbd>Ellipses</kbd> + <kbd>Balloons button</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>) whilst the Stadia controller was plugged into my PC via USB3.

Now Chrome wants to reconnect to the controller but no longer sees it. Do I need a Bluetooth wireless adapter on my PC for the next steps to happen, i.e. to download and install new firmware?

The controller is definitely >10% charged (and I gave it an extra charge) otherwise you're prevented from even starting the procedure.

Comment: I wouldn't think so. One thing I noticed on the beginning page is the system requirements `System requirements: Chrome 108 or newer`. I'd check that. Watching a video on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oR3bL2d1iUI), when trying to connect through the Chrome device list again it says `The Stadia controller name could be ST Blank RT Family, Stadia Controller, or USB COMPOSITE DEVICE` It sounds like you're seeing none of those options?

Comment: @DrZoo I'm running Chrome 113 and you're correct, I don't see any device names listed.

Answer (score 1):

When I started the Stadia controller unlock process I had it plugged into a USB3 Type A socket on the front of my PC case. It's a Corsair 4000D Airflow that has  USB3 Type A and Type C sockets that connect to the motherboard via a Corsair provided cable and plug.

I decided to try plugging the controller into one of the motherboard (Asus Prime B660-PLUS D4) rear USB2 sockets. This allowed Chrome to see my partially reset controller and then complete the unlocking procedure.